# Marketing Cloud: Retrieve Subscribers API request (SOAP)

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to retrieve subscribers with information mentioned here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve_a_subscriber_via_the_web_service_api.htm

Tried to use the same soap envelope in SOAPUI and my request looks like below:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
<fueloauth>TOKEN</fueloauth>
</Header>
      <Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailTypePreference</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>CreatedDate</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>greaterThan</SimpleOperator>
               <DateValue>2012-01-04T10:19:00</DateValue>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

and request is sent to `https://DOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/ETFramework.wsdl`

I am getting 200 ok as response but the response body is weird very long message and i didnt find any information about subscribers in this response message.

I also tried then to create subscriber using the request from here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_subscriber.htm) and noticed that response status code is 200 ok but the message looks same as what I got earlier for retrieve subscribers. Message is too long to copy paste here ..

Comment: I am not getting any error it says 200 ok but the response is some 30000 lines xml which doesnot have information I am looking for

Comment: iam using your code for its working

Comment: i got the subscriber information

Comment: Should anything be specifically enabled on the user account from which I am getting auth token ?

Comment: use the mc  username and password  instead of token then try ?

Comment: Ok giving it a try..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92774/discussion-between-pkharries-and-sf-user).

Comment: @pkharries I am using your code from the chat, but all I get is response 200 OK, but no other data. I used the envelope you had in chat with username and password and this endpoint https://{{subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx

Comment: Using the s7 URL doesn't work either. I'm using Postman to make my requests.

Comment: I was able to get this working using the ListSubscriber object and Token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question notes that you're sending requests to `https://DOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/ETFramework.wsdl` (this will only give you descriptions of the service).

The SOAP service endpoint to retrieve the data you want should actually be `https://DOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx`.

Comment: Thanks Mark.. that I believe is the first one... but now it says "login failed" when i am able to generate token using clientid and password and using the same token in `fueloauth`

Comment: @sf_user Ensure the token you're using hasn't expired (have you tried generating a new one?) and that the subdomains between the two endpoints (subdomains.auth.marketingcloudapis & subdomains.soap.marketingcloudapis) match.

Comment: I tried generating new token and used and same issue.. login failed.. but how to check subdomains match between 2 endpoints ?

Comment: when i am using fueloauth and use a token i am getting `<faultstring>Login Failed</faultstring>
` and when i use usernametoken I am getting `
<faultstring>An invalid security token was provided</faultstring>`

Comment: @sf_user Compare the request URLs you're using to generate your token and retrieve the subscribers—do the unique strings after the `https://` but before the `marketingcloudapis` domain match? As for your invalid security token, see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/122776/55245

Comment: yes they are matching .. domain name is same on both URLs

Answer (score 1):

this code for create subscriber in list

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Header>
 <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity- 
secext-1.0.xsd">
   <UsernameToken>
   <Username>****</Username>
   <Password>xxxxx</Password>
   </UsernameToken>
  </Security>
 </Header>
<Body>
  <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <Options>
</Options>
<Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
 <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true">
 </PartnerKey>
<ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
</ObjectID>

<EmailAddress>saomr@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
<SubscriberKey>saomr@gmail.com</SubscriberKey>
 <Attributes>
<Name>FirstName</Name>
<Value>Bob</Value>
</Attributes>
<Attributes>
<Name>LastName</Name>
<Value>Somelastname</Value>
</Attributes>
<Lists>
  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true">
 </PartnerKey>
 <ID>**LISt ID here**</ID>
<ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
</ObjectID>
 </Lists>
 </Objects>
 </CreateRequest>
 </Body>
 </Envelope>
```